# PHP blank page instead of parse error (all config for error reporting checked)

Tags: php, linux, apache

I know this question was already posted but I did not find an answer regarding a specific case. I verified on my VPS all php.ini (general and local) settings, enabling to report all possible errors, parse errors as well.

I also enabled again the single page the error reporting, to be sure.

Most of the times I get errors and notices, but I have a particular case where I get just a blank page (for a parse error), and no error logged anywhere (etc/httpd/logs/error_log or suphp_log). If I write a wrong line like this one below (real case)

```
$email = $_GET['email';]
```

instead of the correct

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
```

I get a completely blank page, no errors nowhere, nothing...how is this possible? I have CentOS 6 with latest Apache and PHP on my VPS.

Comment: To be sure, put this code on the begining of the file > `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: you have to use globally or internally 

<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);
@error_reporting(E_ALL);
?> or can you share you INI or phpinfo()

Comment: @Glavić your solution worked!